# How to create a button and modify value when I click it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, promise

I'm working on a chatroom website, I want to create buttons and change global value when I click it.

But there is no any response when I click it (variable doesn't change), I tried to print the Promise of creating the button, but it displays 'PromiseState: pending'.

Am I coding wrong in somewhere?

Thanks.

```js
// i is chatroom's name.
let ref = database.ref("chatroom/chat/" + i + "/user");

ref.once("value", src => {
    if (src.hasChild(user.uid)) {
        
        let add = new Promise(() => {
            $("#chatBtn").append(chatroomHText(i));
        });

        add.then(() => {
            $("#chat-" + i).click(() => {
                current_chatroom = i;
            });
        });
    }
});

function chatroomHText(i) {
    return ('<button type="button" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" id="chat-' + i + '">' + i + "</button>");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// i is chatroom's name.
let ref = database.ref("chatroom/chat/" + i + "/user");

ref.once("value", src => {
    if (src.hasChild(user.uid)) {
        
        let add = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $("#chatBtn").append(chatroomHText(i));
            resolve(); // You are missing this part.
        });

        add.then(() => {
            $("#chat-" + i).click(() => {
                current_chatroom = i;
            });
        });
    }
});

function chatroomHText(i) {
    return ('<button type="button" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" id="chat-' + i + '">' + i + "</button>");
}
```